# Duplicate Display on Windows but there is single Screen connected

Tags: windows, windows-10, display-settings

When I go to display settings, it's showing that the display is duplicated to 2 screens. But there is single screen connected to this device. What may be the reason for this?

Windows 10 Enterprize

[image]

Comment: How many display adaptor you can see in device manager??

Comment: 1 display adapter (Intel HD Graphics). But 2 entries "Generic PnP Monitor" in "Monitors".

Comment: Remove generic  PNP monitor.

Comment: What are these generic pnp monitors? Should I remove both?

Comment: If you have driver missing it shows Generic PNP. Try to uninstall it both. And try scan for devices again. If it shows you canagain.Then you have to update the drivers. Third party tool like driver identifier. Download it and scan it.. you can see update for that monitor drivers. Update it. To latest one